# Command to simulate keyboard input

Tags: command-line, x11, keyboard

Is there a command that exists that can simulate keypresses? I want to pipe some data to it to make it type into a GUI program for me.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, it is `xdotool`.

To simulate a key press, use:

```
xdotool key <key>
```

For example, to simulate pressing `F2`:

```
xdotool key F2
```

To simulate pressing `crtl + c`:

```
xdotool key ctrl+c
```

To simulate pressing `ctrl + c` and then a `Backspace`:

```
xdotool key ctrl+c BackSpace
```

Check `man xdotool` to get more idea.

You might need to install the `xdotool` package first to use `xdotool` command.

Comment: Sweet! I'm assuming people use this for remote connections?

Comment: @SpecialBomb Depends..i use it sometimes to simulate a key inside a script..

Comment: Well, thanks! I'm going to use it specifically to make my own remote connection thing.

Comment: I used it so that my computer wouldn't sleep while I was watching movies.

Comment: What :key syntax is it to enter UP arrow key? Found it here as `xdotool key Up` https://askubuntu.com/q/382005/22308

Comment: This lags out my PC

Answer (score 2):

Use `expect`  ([man expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect))

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
#set timeout 10
set clientName [lindex $argv 0];
set hostName [lindex $argv 1];
set passWord [lindex $argv 2];

spawn ssh "$hostName";
expect "Password:";
send "$passWord\r";
expect "$hostName";

send "cd /apps/bin\r";
expect " bin]";
```

Comment: `expect` won't work with GUI programs.