# Is there any way to open the menu without using panel in Cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, command, cinnamon

Main Cinnamon menu is the default menu applet on Linux Mint Cinnamon, and as far as I understand it can't be run without the panel. Is there any command for opening the menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a slightly roundabout way to do this. There is a tool called `xdotool` that can simulate a keypress. `xdotool key super` will "press" the super key and thus open the menu.

`sudo apt install xdotool` will install the package.

Source: [Command to simulate keyboard input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267704/command-to-simulate-keyboard-input)

Answer (score 0):

No, user cannot open the menu without using panel.

There are only two ways to open the menu: Press the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Super L</kbd> or <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>, or click the menu button on panel with mouse pointer.

There is no command to open the menu. This is not just Cinnamon, but also true even with different panel and applet, extension, or plugin. Instead of providing command to open the main menu, such feature is often built-in.

One exception is Xfce. There are two menu plugins for Xfce panel: [Applications Menu](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/applicationsmenu) (built-in) and [Whisker Menu](https://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin). Despite Xfce documentation does not mention the command usage for respective menu, user can indeed open the menu in Xfce without using panel or by using command (these are two different conditions).

Another exception is LXDE. More specifically, the default panel for LXDE. lxpanel has its own controller that provides the command to open the menu for itself.

Cinnamon and major desktop environments just can't do that.